# Git push origin master updating pull request but not my repo

Tags: git, github, pull-request

So I forked someone's repo, cloned it locally and made some changes. I made a pull reuqest and that guy wanted me to add something. So after my changes done locally, i did ( everything was done in the master branch)

```
Git add .
git commit -m 'added text'
git push origin master
```

So this basically took my changes and updated the pull request without me creating another one. My question is, what if i wanted to just push the changes to the forked repo on my github without updating the pull request? In this case, the pull request was updated and he recived the edited version. How would i push so that the changes only go to my repo and not the pull request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create a new branch for each pull request you make.

[Github says:](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/#sending-the-pull-request)

> After your pull request is sent, any new commits pushed to your branch will automatically be added to the pull request.

So if you want your new commits not to go on that PR, you may create a new branch using :

```
git checkout -b new_branch
[commit]
git push origin new_branch
```

And then create a pull request from that branch. So you master is free for you to commit again.

Comment: Nice answer, in general I would always create a branch for each pull request.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! So you're saying that all the changes I make will go into new_branch instead of master, meaning the master in my forked repo will always remain the same ( the original forked). All changes will be in new_branch which will contain the original + the changes? And then I can push from that new_branch to the repo's owner's master branch? Am i understanding this correctly?

Comment: ^ This is assuming I haven't made any pull requests yet. Just trying to get how new branches work

Comment: That it. Master will "point" to the version you've forked from, with no change. Then you can create a branch, push change there, and ask the upstream to merge your branch with his master.